# How to add icon with function to MDToolBbar with python?

Tags: python, kivy

This is well explained and logical on how to do it with the kv format.

Problem: I need to make theses buttons evolve dynamically.

Solution: Create a function that does it in python.

Problem: I didn't saw any code about that on [the doc](https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/toolbar/index.html).

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder

KV = '''
BoxLayout:
    MDToolbar:
        id: mytoolbar
        elevation: 5
        left_action_items: [["menu",lambda x: data.data_manager.app.left_item_click()]]
        right_action_items: [["send-outline", lambda x: x],["file-document-box-plus-outline", lambda x: x],["content-save-outline", lambda x: lambda x: x],["home", lambda x: lambda x: x]]

'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.screen = Builder.load_string(KV)
    def build(self):
        return self.screen

    def add_icon_on_mdtoolbar_with_python(self, icon, func):
        pass
        self.screen.ids["mytoolbar"].SOMETHING(icon,func)

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`self.screen.ids["mytoolbar"].right_action_items = [["send-outline", lambda x: x]]`
You just have to recreate the "attribute/method" of the toolbar witht the new icons.